# Programmatic UI: How to reference UITableView created in a custom UIView for View Controller outside of the custom UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

My app is being done completely programmatically so no StoryBoard or nil/xib files.
My app consists of a UITabBar controller with two tabs and each tab has a navigation bar. The first tab I have not yet worked on so its blank (MenuViewController) at the moment. The second one (CafeViewController) will have a Vertical Stack View (On Safe Area) that has a MKMapView on the top half and a UITableView on the bottom half.

I created a custom UIView for the my CafesViewController which is where I have the stack view. In that custom UIView I put the code for my mapView and tableView and added all the constraints.  What I want help with is how would I go on setting the delegate and datasource for the tableView from the CafesViewController. I don't know how to reference the tableView from the CafesViewController.

What I have tried is to create a reference by creating a tableView on the CafesViewController, but I soon realized that it will actually create another tableView and its not the same one from my custom view. I have searched online on how to do this but I cannot find how to do it entirely programmatically and with the tableView located in the custom view. Note: I know the view and tableView can be done from the view controller but I am trying to keep my view controller as clean as possible by refactoring as much as I can.

My goal is to learn this first step in how to reference the tableView first and then learn to refactor the tableView delegate and datasources to be separate from the CafesViewController.

Here are some pics of my custom UIView and my CafesViewController (The main controller I am working on currently)

[Custom UIView for the CafesViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7qip.png)

[CafesViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWJUl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do it like:

In CustomUIView, define two weak references like this:

```
weak var delegate : UITableViewDelegate? = nil {
    didSet{
        self.tableView.delegate = delegate
    }
}

weak var dataSource : UITableViewDataSource? = nil {
    didSet{
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
    }
}
```

and in your viewController, in loadView method:

```
var cafesView : CafesView = CafesView()
cafesView.delegate = self
cafesView.dataSource = self
self.view = cafesView
```

Then, you can simply implement these two protocols in your ViewController.